# Extract values from mysql and edit in php form

Tags: php, mysql

I have an edit form that retrieve person's information from database and fill them to textbox in a form to let the user to edit his info. , the problem is: when the field is a sentence (i.e. Full name) it prints only the first word(which is the first name). my code is:

```
  <label class ="label">Enter your full name</label>
          <input type="text" name="Name"  class="textbox" value= <?php echo $row["Name"]?> required/>
```

even though when I tried to `echo $row["Name"]`, it prints it fully.

thanks in advance,

Comment: You need to list all the name related fields in the database. Is it like Name? Or like first_name, last_name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you're missing quotes around the value attribute, try:

```
 <label class ="label">Enter your full name</label>
      <input type="text" name="Name"  class="textbox" value="<?php echo $row["Name"]?>" required/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use as follows: suppose you have users table to store the user information then.

```
$query = mysql_query('select *from users where id=2'); //you can use dynamic 
$rec=mysql_fetch_array($query);
 <label class ="label">Enter your full name</label>
          <input type="text" name="Name"  class="textbox" value= <?php echo $rec["name"];?> required/>
```

where the name is the column name from database table

Answer (score 1):

Use value in double-quote `$row['Name']` in single-quote

```
<label class ="label">Enter your full name</label>
      <input type="text" name="Name"  class="textbox" value="<?php echo $row['Name']?"> required/>
```